# AngularTS - $scope.$apply causes controller to stop loading

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Whenever I run the application, the angular {{ }} stay. If I remove $scope.$apply the braces go away and the proper value is shown.

I am using Angular + Typescript.

Controller:

```
module Application.Controllers {
export class TestController {

    public hello: string = "hello";

    private scope: any;

    constructor($scope: ng.IScope) {

        this.scope = $scope;
        this.scope.hello = "Hi";
        this.scope.$apply();

        alert('no errors');

    }

}
```

}

Controller Definition (in an initialization function a few seconds after the app loads):

```
var appController2 = AppModule.controller("TestCTRL", ["$scope", Application.Controllers.TestController]);
```

The view:

```
    <div ng-controller="TestCTRL as t">
        <div>{{ t.hello }} {{ 1 - 1 }}</div>
    </div>
```

Instead of seeing "Hello 0" I see  {{ t.hello }} {{ 1 - 1 }}

If I remove the this.scope.$apply call, it works, but it shows hello instead of hi.

I am using IE 11, Angular 1.4.9

I also have 2 other working controllers in my DOM, and whenever it gets to this one it stops unless I remove $scope.$apply

Comment: Any errors in the console? In my experience when angular fails to bind its thrown an exception and fallen over.

Comment: 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress

Comment: Well there you go.
There is no need for `$apply` as its already running. Why do you need it anyway? Are things not binding as you expect? If so @JBNizet answer may be the solution. Generally speaking the use of `$apply` is minimal, usually only when things happen outside of angulars domain, say a jQuery event.

Comment: The data wasn't binding correctly for one of my other controllers, so I made a test controller and placed a few values in it. I don't think it was loading correctly because I was using the this.scope as opposed to the direct variable.

Comment: Yea, @JBNizet answer sounds like a solution. Also just to note `$apply` is meant to tell angular the scope has changed without its knowing and update the bindings. Also you called `$apply` without passing it a function. thats not the best way to use it, if an error was thrown angular wouldn't catch it and perform your error handling. I know you wasn't in this specific case but just an FYI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two `hello` fields: one is a field of the controller, whose value is "hello", available in the view using `{{ t.hello }}`, and the other is a field of the scope, whose value is "hi", available in the view using `{{ hello }}`, or, since you stored the scope in a field of the controller, using `{{ t.scope.hello }}`.

If you want a single field, then use

```
this.hello = "Hi";
```

instead of

```
this.scope.hello = "Hi";
```

When using controllerAs, you typically don't store anything into the scope. And most of the time, you don't even need the scope.